# What is the difference between 'ls --color' and 'ls --color=tty'?

Tags: shell, unix

I am making an alias for `ls` in my `.zshrc` profile so that it always has a colored output. As it turns out, I stumbled across either

```
alias ls="ls --color=tty"
```

or, without the `tty` value

```
alias ls="ls --color"
```

Is there any particular situation where either the commands `$ ls --color=tty` and `$ ls --color`, or the above aliases, can behave differently ?

Comment: what's "undesired" depends on what the user desires. Maybe they *do* want color codes in the output of `ls | tee file.log` even though it makes the log file less readable, or perhaps they don't (for that same reason or any other). If there weren't a question in terms of what someone might want, there wouldn't be a need for more than one option.

Comment: Yes, got it. `ls --color | less` and `ls --color=tty | less` produce *different* results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With no argument attached to the option (`--color`), the output is always colorized. With `--color=tty`, it is only colorized when stdout is connected to a tty. This matters when the output of `ls` is piped or redirected.

Comment: Note that `ls --color=auto` accomplishes the same task. My version of `ls` doesn't even document the `tty` option in favor of `auto`.